# Android - Flashing hardware buttons for missed calls

Tags: android, button, hardware

My old Nokia phone was flashing hardware buttons when I missed a call. So I was able to understand that I have missed a call just by looking to phone. With my new Android phone I have to reach my phone and wake the screen to see if I have missed a call.

I have searched Android market but could not find exact application to solve my problem. So I have decided to write it. The question is how can I turn on and off back lid of hardware buttons of a android phone?

I have googled it but could not find a clean answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does have [notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) for that purpose, the backlight is not thought to be controlled through the API (you could do it on rooted devices but thats another story).

Personally, I dedinitely do get notifications for missed calls, and my notification LED blinks. However, you can implement your own notifications:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// create a new notification
CharSequence tickerText = "Missed call";
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

// control how the notification led should behave
notification.ledARGB = 0xff00ff00;
// blink for 300ms every 1s
notification.ledOnMS = 300;
notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

// usually you also want to create a PendingIntent and attach it 
// with notification.setLatestEventInfo

// finally, post the notification to the notification manager
notificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
```

There are many other options for notifications, like vibration or `FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL`, but they are [documented very well](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) ;-)

---

On a rooted device, you could execute the following to control the backlight (however, I would recommend sticking to the intended way, which are notifications):

```
su
echo 25 > /sys/class/leds/button-backlight-portrait/currents
echo 25 > /sys/class/leds/button-backlight-landscape/currents
```

where `25` would be the brightness. But admittetly, I don't know for sure if this would even work on **all** devices.